# Is there a workaround in cPanel for email plus addressing for misbehaving sites?

Tags: email, cpanel

I'm trying to use Email Filters in cPanel on mxroute to work around misbehaving sites that don't support [email plus addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Subaddressing) (as described [here](https://twitter.com/gtbvchanan/status/982592348155727877)). In short, replacing the "+" with another character that's commonly accepted like "-" and forwarding it just like it were a "+".

The rule part works great:

```
Any Recipient - matches regex
me-(.*?)@mydomain.com
```

However, when I try to save the following action:

```
Redirect to email
me+$1@mydomain.com
```

I get the following error:

> Filter destination paths cannot contain mailboxes that start with the “~” character or contain the following characters: “@”, “$”, “"”, and “\0”

It lets me save when I change it to `me@mydomain.com`, but that's not what I want since it prevents the email from being stored in the appropriate folder. **I'd also rather not create a separate rule for each possible email address.**

I figured I'd be able to do this with regex since I thought cPanel Email Filters were just a UI over Exim ([which appears to support rewrite patterns](https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-address_rewriting.html#SECID151)).

Is this possible using Email Filters? Does the UI accept the pattern in some other format? Is there another way to do this in cPanel with limited access like is present in mxroute?

Comment: This email misbehaviour is a real bug-bear of mine. So many web forms are misconfigured and prevent valid email addresses.

Answer (score -1):

Why not create a cpanel forwarder?  `me@example.com -> me+whatever@example.com` and you then use `me@example.com` where you need to.

FWIW, you could even do this in gmail.  If you had an email `example@gmail.com`, in `settings > accounts and forwarders` you can forward that to `me+whatever@example.com`,  In this case `example@gmail.com` is what you publish.

If you want to take it one step further, if you could get `me@gmail.com` a valid email address is `me+whatever@gmail.com` so it kind of matches the original, and you could publish that.  This method is useful if you sign up at various sites, you can track if they pass on your email address e.g. `me+stackexchange@gmail.com`

Comment: Sounds like you're describing doing the opposite of what I'm asking. I'm wanting to give a service provider that doesn't support plus signs a different, but similar email and have cPanel forward it to the plus address (e.g. `me-finance.wellsfargo@mydomain.com` goes to `me+finance.wellsfargo@mydomain.com`). I said `-` because it's more supported than `+`.

Comment: @TaylorBuchanan No I'm not.   Re-read what I said.  Your non + email address will forward to your + email address.

Comment: I've read what you said. Please explain how forwarding `me@example.com` to `me+whatever@example.com` does anything I'm asking. That's exactly what is stated in your first paragraph. If you're suggesting I forward every variation of `-` email separately, I clearly stated this in my question: "I'd also rather not create a separate rule for each possible email address."

Comment: I thought I would create a visual example of what I am talking about, but when I tried to add me+testing@example.com in cpanel I received the error "You can only enter letters, numbers, periods, hyphens, and underscores." so how are you creating these emails in the first place?

Comment: I think that's where the misunderstanding lies. You don't _create_ email plus addresses. They are implicitly supported by cPanel. See [here](https://confluence1.cpanel.net/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=2440525#content/view/2440525) under Email subaddresses.

Comment: The problem is that many, many incorrectly written web forms and the like will not accept a valid email address like `me+whatever@gmail.com` so, the OP wants to submit `me-whatever@gmail.com` and have it handed as if it had the +.